# Multiple EC2 instances using Vagrant

Tags: ruby, json, amazon-web-services, hash, vagrant

I'm trying out Vagrant to provision an environment with multiple EC2 instances in AWS (using [vagrant-aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) plugins) and using a JSON config file for Vgrant to read from. Below is the JSON file:

```
macp-3:vagrant-aws sans$ cat scripts/aws.json
{
    "env": "dops",
    "access_key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "secret_key": "hfgy5ejfkprg2432432beqo2r",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "availability_zone": "a",
    "subnet_id": "subnet-0b766860",
    "security_groups": [
        "sg-53t48c34",
        "sg-11668f7e",
        "sg-4a6c8525",
        "sg-75168c1e"
    ],
    "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
    "keypair": "Xdops_testKey",
    "ssh_private_key": "/Users/sans/.ssh/id_rsa",
    "ec2s": {
        "dops-agg-001": {
            "ami_id": "ami-838675f7",
            "instance_type": "m3.medium",
            "elastic_ip": "ture",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "dops-agg-001",
                "Role": "sql-aggr",
                "ServiceType": "database",
                "NopeType": "mem_master",
                "CostCentre": "QA"
            }
        },
        "dops-nag-001": {
            "ami_id": "ami-838675f7",
            "instance_type": "m3.medium",
            "elastic_ip": "ture",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "dops-nag-001",
                "Role": "monitoring",
                "ServiceType": "controller",
                "NopeType": "nagios",
                "CostCentre": "QA"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Vagrantfile` that I've come up with:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

aws_cfg = (JSON.parse(File.read("scripts/aws.json")))

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "dummy"
    config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"

    aws_cfg['ec2s'].each do |node|
        node_name  = node[0]
        node_value = node[1]

        # Node specific configuration
        config.vm.define node_name do |config2|
            ec2_tags = node_value['tags']

            # Spining up EC2 instances
            config2.vm.provider :aws do |ec2, override|
                ec2.access_key_id = aws_cfg['access_key']
                ec2.secret_access_key = aws_cfg['secret_key']
                ec2.keypair_name = aws_cfg['keypair']
                ec2.region = aws_cfg['region']
                ec2.availability_zone = aws_cfg['region']+aws_cfg['availability_zone']
                ec2.subnet_id = aws_cfg['subnet_id']
                ec2.security_groups = aws_cfg['security_groups']
                #
                ec2.ami = node_value['ami_id']
                ec2.instance_type = node_value['instance_type']
                ec2.elastic_ip = node_value['elastic_ip']
                #
                ec2.tags = {
                    'Name'         => ec2_tags['Name'],
                    'Role'         => ec2_tags['Role'],
                    'ServiceType'  => ec2_tags['ServiceType'],
                    'NopeType'     => ec2_tags['NopeType'],
                    'CostCentre'   => ec2_tags['CostCentre']
                }
                #
                override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
                override.ssh.private_key_path = "/Users/sans/.ssh/id_rsa"
            end

            # Final Puppet provisioning
            #config2.vm.provision :puppet do |ppt|
            #    ppt.options = "--verbose --debug"
            #    ppt.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
            #    ppt.manifest_file  = "nodes.pp"
            #    ppt.module_path = "puppet/modules"
            #end
        end
    end
end
```

It's working okay but trying to spin up the boxes in parallel, instead of one-by-one:

```
macp-3:vagrant-aws sans$ vagrant up --provider=aws
Bringing machine 'dops-agg-001' up with 'aws' provider...
Bringing machine 'dops-mon-001' up with 'aws' provider...
[fog][WARNING] Unable to load the 'unf' gem. Your AWS strings may not be properly encoded.
==> dops-mon-001: HandleBoxUrl middleware is deprecated. Use HandleBox instead.
==> dops-mon-001: This is a bug with the provider. Please contact the creator
==> dops-agg-001: HandleBoxUrl middleware is deprecated. Use HandleBox instead.
==> dops-mon-001: of the provider you use to fix this.
....
....
```

I believe there are some problem with looping in the Vagrantfile? Can anyone tell me what's going wring here? Best!

Answer (score 1):

This question has been [answered in a Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/6ydLWdMgeDc).

**Solution:**

`--[no-]parallel` - Bring multiple machines up in parallel if the provider supports it.